# Powershell ParseExact Date formatting yyyyMMdd issue

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon,

Can someone tell me how to convert the date 20120624 into yyyyMMdd using powershell as I get "String was not recognised as a valud datetime" when running the following code

```
[String]$ServiceTag = "b26ybt1";

Try{ 
       $AssetService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://xserv.dell.com/services/AssetService.asmx?WSDL"; 
       $ApplicationName = "AssetService"; 
       $Guid = [Guid]::NewGuid(); 
       $Asset = $AssetService.GetAssetInformation($Guid,$ApplicationName,$ServiceTag); 
       $Writer = New-Object "System.IO.StringWriter"; 
       $XmlSerializer = New-Object System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer($Asset.GetType()); 
       $XmlSerializer.Serialize($Writer,$Asset); 
       [String]$Result = $Writer.ToString(); 
       $Writer.Flush(); 
       $Writer.Close(); 
       Return $Result; 
} 
Catch{ 
       Write-Host $($_.Exception.Message);     
}

$prog = [regex]::match($Result,'(?<=StartDate>)(.*)(?=T00)').Groups[1].Value
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($prog,"[-]","");

[datetime]::ParseExact($prog,"yyyyMMdd",$null)
```

Comment: What you posted worked perfectly for me. Is this the exact code that you are running?

Comment: pasted all code above, im trying to get a dell purchase date from the website. it works for me if I just used the bit I pasted actually its when the whole thing runs it fails

Comment: Complete information often leads to a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($prog,"[-]","");
```

to

```
$prog = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($prog,"[-]","");
```

All you did was return what the replacement would do, you never actually assigned it to a variable.  When I ran it as above, I got the following:

```
Sunday, June 24, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, how would I store this in a variable as 24/06/2012?

Comment: $date = Get-Date $([datetime]::ParseExact($prog,"yyyyMMdd",$null)) -format MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the result to XML instead of a String and avoid string parsing:

```
[xml]$Result = $Writer.ToString()
[datetime]$Result.ArrayOfAsset.Asset.Entitlements.EntitlementData[0].StartDate
```